# Restrict IAM Role to CRUD CloudFormation stacks with specific tags

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

We have multiple teams that shares a common AWS production account. We want every team to get an own IAM Role that enables them to create close to all types of resources (AdministratorAccess). 
But to separate the teams not modify each others stacks we need a mechanism to prevent that from happen.

What are the options to achieve this?

Comment: If this requires an admin to do the stack-creation would that still fit your use case? For example, I havent tried it yet but it should be easy to inject the ARN for the teamA role into the stack and apply a policy of update,delete just for that stack. But to prevent team A from running updates on other stacks they have to be pinned to a specific resource or stack when they're role is created, so they wouldn't be allowed to create anything new. Would this be too restrictive?

Comment: The team should be the admin from the very start of the creation of the stack. So for example I like to create a policy on a role that only enables creation/update/deletes on stacks with specific tag an value.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `Condition` field in the policy document.

For example, the below policy will ensure that you can only Delete / Reboot / Modify the DBInstance, only if your username is tagged as the *Owner*.

```
  {
      "Action": [
          "rds:DeleteDBInstance",
          "rds:RebootDBInstance",
          "rds:ModifyDBInstance"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
          "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
              "rds:db-tag/Owner": "${aws:username}"
          }
      }
  }
```

Please visit [Example Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html) for other examples.

Hope this helps!!